# Create controls dynamically or create controls in a side form? C# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form full of controls, and there is no room for other controls. On the bottom of the form I have a panel with some controls on it.

My goal is that when a certain button is clicked, the original panel on the bottom will be replaced with another panel that contains controls which could be created before the program starts, meaning these controls in the panel do not need to be created dynamically. The replace action would be executed by setting each panel's visible field to it's matched value.

I have thought of two ways of doing this - either creating the new panel (and it's controls) dynamically and adding it to the form instead of the original, or creating the new panel in another form and when the relevant button is clicked the panel being taken from that form and added to the required form (by creating an instance of the new form and making it's panel's modifier public). The "side form"'s purpose is only to create that panel, it has no functionality of it's own.

The advantages of creating the new panel dynamically:

- There is no need to create a zero-functionality form.

The advantages of creating the new panel in a side form:

- It's very clear which controls are added to the new panel and their positions.
- It's very easy to set the location and other fields of the controls in the new panel.

Which way is better?

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes using controls like TAB etc. turns out to be the best option...think over those lines as well..

Comment: @Arif I already have some tabs, I want to add the new panel to the selected tab..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered TabControl? That seems a good fit for your needs. Other controls I can think of are StackPanel (Can be fairly easily done for Windows Forms) or OutlookBar like control (again a user control).

Simplest and quickest way seems to be TabControl.

Edit:

1. SideForm is a different windows form I suppose. So if you are thinking to make controls public and then change their visibility etc, please don't. Use delegates  to handle SideForm's events in MainForm.
2. As you mentioned, there is no room for more controls, I would suggest more screens rather than just one. Having said that I do not know much about your current UI design and functionality so it's up to you.

I would say having the controls hidden and just playing with the Visibility is fine. This means that you do not have to worry about positioning of controls, anchoring and docking at runtime. The problem could well be loading of form. Having huge number of controls having a lot of data associated with them may slow things down.

Comment: As I said to @Arif I already have some tabs, I want to add the new panel to the selected tab..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1) SideForm is indeed another form. I don't mean to change SideForm's controls visibility, I intend to take the panel from SideForm and copy it to the MainForm and then change the visibilty of the original panel in the MainForm. 2) The user insist on having that panel on MainForm. I cannot create the 2 panels in the MainForm because there is no room in the form to make it.

Comment: So you are going to provide drag drop feature?

Comment: No. why should I? after I took the panel from the SideForm and copied it to MainForm, each time the button is clicked the other panel is shown and the current showed panel is getting hidden.

Comment: What do you mean when you say copied it to MainForm?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14173/discussion-between-danish-and-remi)

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best way would be to utilise user controls for this purpose. Simply create one user control per panel you wish to show/hide and place your controls inside. This way you will have both: the designer and the "extra form" you wanted.